# Problem with the curl's definition

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $A$ be a surface with a simple, smooth and closed boundary $\partial A$ in $\Bbb R^3$, such that:

$$\lim_{A\to0}A=P$$

The *curl* of a vector field $\vec{F}\in C^2$ at $P$ is defined as:

$$\left(\vec\nabla\times\vec{F}\right)\Biggr|_{P}=\left(\lim_{A\to0}\frac{1}{|A|}\oint\limits_{\partial A}\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}\right)\cdot d\hat{A}\tag{$\star$}$$

When $d\hat{A}$ is a positively oriented (in accordance with $\partial A$'s orientation) unit normal vector to $A$ at the point $P$.

Let $P=(0,0,0)$ and let $\vec{F}(x,y,z)=(z,x,y)$. We know that $\vec\nabla\times\vec F=(1,1,1)$ at *every* point in $\Bbb R^3$, at $P$ in particular. Thus:

$$\left(\vec\nabla\times\vec{F}\right)\Biggr|_{P}=(1,1,1)$$

Let $A=\left\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2\leq r^2, z=0\right\}$. Note that $\lim_\limits{A\to 0}A=P$ and $d\hat{A}=(0,0,1)$ (This is bad. The $x$ and $y$ components of $d\hat{A}$ cannot be zero! But we'll continute anyway). We need a positively oriented parametrization of $\partial A$; A natural example would be:

$$\partial A(t)=(r\cos(t),r\sin(t),0)\\t\in[0,2\pi]$$

Thus:

$$\oint\limits_{\partial A}\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}=\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\Big((0,r\cos(t),r\sin(t))\cdot(-r\sin(t),r\cos(t),0)\Big)\ dt=\int\limits_0^{2\pi}r^2\cos^2(t)\ dt=\pi r^2$$

However, note that:

$$\left(\lim_{A\to0}\frac{1}{|A|}\oint\limits_{\partial A}\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}\right)\cdot d\hat{A}=\left(\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{1}{\pi r^2}\pi r^2\right)\cdot(0,0,1)=(0,0,1)\neq(1,1,1)$$

How is that possible? It seems that if I multiply the LHS of $(\star)$ by $d\hat{A}$ (instead of the RHS) I get the desired result (I checked that for numerous surfaces), but that's not the definition I encoutered. Also, that wouldn't be a very good definition, since it wouldn't compute all the components of the vector.

Thanks!

Comment: Please see my comments below. $d\hat A$ is the element of oriented surface area that belongs inside a surface integral; some textbooks write it as $\hat n\,dA$, where indeed $\hat n$ is the unit normal vector. In your example, $\hat n = (0,0,1)$, yes, but must you do a surface integral — here a double integral  $\iint _A (...) dx\,dy$.

Answer (score 1):

The definition that you have provided is incorrect; the correct definition is

$$\left(\vec\nabla\times\vec{F}\right)\Biggr|_{P}\cdot \hat{n}=\left(\lim_{A\to0}\frac{1}{|A|}\oint\limits_{\partial A}\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}\right)\tag{$\star$}$$

Here, $\hat{n}$ is a vector normal to the surface which you call $A$ (this is equivalent to your defined d$\hat{A}$). We then read this formula as "the curl of the vector field $\vec{F}$ normal to the surface $A$ is equal to the limit as the area of the surface $A$ goes to zero of the line integral of $\vec{F}$ around the surface." By wisely choosing your surfaces, you are able to determine the each component of the curl in any coordinate system.

Had you written the equation in this format, you would arrive at

$$(1,1,1)\cdot(0,0,1)=\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\pi r^2}\pi r^2=1$$

which certainly holds. You were simply using the wrong definition. [Wolfram Alpha](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Curl.html) has the correct definition of the curl. [Here](http://web.mit.edu/6.013_book/www/chapter2/2.4.html) is the web.mit definition, consistent with what I have written above.

Let's further dispute your definition. We can create the exact same circular surface that you have created, but rotate it by some angle $\theta$. Now the direction of the curl at the point $(0,0,0)$ is a function of $\theta$, because by rotating my surface, I am changing the normal direction to the surface and, by the definition you have provided, that changes the curl. But recall that for a function, the curl is a function of position, yet I can generate from your formula an *infinite* number of results for every single point. Thus the curl would have no meaning as it would take on an infinite number of values for every point in space unless the curl was exactly zero, in which case it would have one value.

Comment: A scalar dotted with a vector gives a vector, for example: $3 \cdot (1,1,1)$ would be $(3,3,3)$, of course, where $3$ is our scalar and $(1,1,1)$ is the vector. The definition might not be true, but it makes sense - both the LHS and RHS are vectors. The definition can be seen also on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)#Definition

Comment: Your equation ($\star$) makes no sense to me. I don't care what web sources have it. On the left I have no idea what $d\hat A$ means; it should just be a fixed unit vector, say $\hat v$. Then, on the right, you should consider, say, (piecewise smooth) planar regions through $P$ with normal $\hat v$ and whose areas approach $0$.

Comment: No reputable mathematics textbook has such a definition. (I have 45+ years experience teaching multivariable calculus and have authored a textbook on it.) $d\hat A$ is an oriented element of surface area, not a vector.